# SIgning users in Django through Google OAuth and using that data to access their Gmail

Tags: django, google-oauth, gmail-api, django-allauth

While signing users in through Google in Django is pretty conventional, I can't seem to figure out how to use that user data that I get upon login to get access to the user's Gmail.

In case i need another authentication step, how do i make it so i remember their Gmail authentication for next time.

Essentially, I need to log in users in my Django app through their Google account and then feed them their Gmail emails on their dashboard.

Tried django allauth and played around but with no results.